# After installing anaconda-2.5.3 in centos 7 , yum and gnome not working

Tags: python, yum

Normally i do the installation from shell command as shown below..

```
sh Anaconda2-5.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

After the installation i realised that some dependencies for the python package `yum` gone missing. So that normal command `yum` not working.. and shows the error as

```
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  1 2018, 23:32:55) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
[bhanuchander@master dailymail]$ yum
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  1 2018, 23:32:55) 
[GCC 7.2.0]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

and also the python normal import shows error as,

```
>>$ python -c 'import yum'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named yum
```

If i restart the system, gnome not working and showing `Oops some thing gone Wrong`. After removing `anaconda` its working fine...

- What is happening here ?
  and How to solve this ?

Comment: Gnome and most of linux library rely on `python 2`. There is a conflict between symbolic links of `/bin/python` (points to `python 2.7.x`) and `/path/to/anaconda/bin/python` (points to `python 3.6.x`).

Comment: @finn I have installed the version 2.7.15 not 3.*. It seems like the latest anaconda doesn't have `yum` related dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

While installing anaconda package you’ll receive the following output after compeletion of installation :

```
Output
...
installation finished.
Do you wish the installer to prepend the Anaconda3 install location
to PATH in your /home/hostname/.bashrc ? [yes|no]
[no] >>>
```

Type `no`

After compeletion of installation. Go to `/path/to/anaconda/bin/` then either remove `python` file. Now, append the `Anaconda3` install locationto PATH in your `~/.bashrc`.

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

add this line to file :

```
export PATH=$HOME/path/to/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

press `:wq`

Now, type reload shell variable :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```